# How to make Selenium IDE open tor mode in Brave Browser as default?

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-ide, tor, brave-browser

When I click record it pops up normal tab in Brave browser instead I want to use tor mode is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

(Taken from https://gist.github.com/ShlomiRex/1d9d7b7b341d8af535b53c657309fcad)

When you add your options to the `webdriver.ChromeOptions` Object (if your'e doing this with python), you can add a line to the options object like this:

```
brave_path = r"your_path"
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
option.add_argument("--tor")
```

The browser then will open with a Tor window